# How can I use Wix Properties

Tags: c#, wix, wix4

I'm working with `Wix v4` to create a msi package. I had the problem, that I must set a Property in a CustomAction (C#) at the beginning of the installation.

This works fine, but now I'm a little bit confused. The property can't be used in all my cases.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">
```

```
<Property Id="ANUMMER" Value="A2000-0000" />

<Binary Id='CustomActionReadConfig' SourceFile='...'/>

<InstallUISequence>
  <!-- Set the property over session["ANUMMER"] = "..." -->
  <Custom Action="CustomActionReadConfig" Before="AppSearch" />
</InstallUISequence>
```

The ini file hasn't a problem

```
    <IniFile Id="Programm.ini" Action="createLine" Key="ANUMMER" Name="Programm.ini" Section="Programm" Value="[ANUMMER]" Directory="Dir" />
```

For the directory I found the follow workaround

```
<SetDirectory Action="SetApplicationFolder" Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]\[COMPANYNAME]\[MYPROGRAMM]\[ANUMMER]"  Sequence="ui"/>
```

But the shortcuts can' use it and I didn't find a workaround

```
<Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="Programm [ANUMMER]" WorkingDirectory="Dir" Advertise="yes" Icon="DesktopIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" />
    <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="Programm" WorkingDirectory="Dir" Advertise="yes" Icon="StartMenuIcon.exe" IconIndex="0">
      <ShortcutProperty Key="Name" Value="Programm [ANUMMER]"/>
    </Shortcut>
```

Like this, I need this property in some further cases. Do I use it wrong or do I have to use an special escape combination? Can't I use properties in Name attributes? Is there an other way, to use the input as variable witch I can set in the CustomAction? Or what is the basic problem, that I can't use such a custom runtime property in sutch ways?

Thanks for help

Comment: Try setting your property as `Secure="yes"`

Comment: Thanks, but it dosen't help. This attribute of [property](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/property.html) is for server actions

Comment: @RPC161: quoting the documentation doesn't make Brian wrong. He's correct. The "server" part here is because a Windows Installer install has a client process and a server process, and unless Secure is set the public properties will not transfer from the client UI/inititialization process into the actual install process. So Secure must be set true, even if it's not your immediate issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for further options I found the reason for the problem for this in an other question here: [Dynamically assigning name to shortcut at run time in WIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524114/dynamically-assigning-name-to-shortcut-at-run-time-in-wix)

The property value can be used in [Formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx) type. I wanted to use it in LongFileNameType (Simple Type) or in strings.

If someone knows a way, to fill a variable at runtime to solve this problem, it would be nice to share it with us.

Info: The value could also be a localization variable with the format !(loc.VARIABLE).